# Submit two forms to one action Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, partial-views

I'm trying to submit two forms to one action. I can't figure out is it a good idea and how to do better. Each form has it own partial view and both forms using same model. I mean model is divided by forms.

Here is view model and model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    // here is some other data for main form
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Foo foo)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Main view:

```
@model SushiJazz.Models.ViewModels.TestViewModel
<body>
    <div id="frmName">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("NameFrm"); }
    </div>
    <div id="frmStreet">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("StreetFrm"); }
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit"  value="btn" id="btn-submit"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

First form:

```
@model SushiJazz.Models.ViewModels.TestViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { @id="name-frm"}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Foo.Name);
    <input type="submit" value="name" />
}
```

Second form:

```
@model SushiJazz.Models.ViewModels.TestViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { @id="street-frm"}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Foo.Street)
    <input type="submit" value="street" />
}
```

I want to submit both forms by btn-submit click to Add action.
I mean not call Add action twice but get Foo.Name and Foo.Street filled from different forms, call Add action and pass fully filled Foo model to it.

Is it possible? Maybe there is some other ways?

Comment: No. You can only submit one form at a time (unless you use ajax to pass the values from all forms in the request). Just have one form that includes the inputs from both models.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're just demonstrating a concept as it doesn't make any sense to split those small pieces into separate partial views in this case.

But just move the `@using (Html.BeginForm...` wrapping from each partial view to include all your mark up in the main view with containing the two `@{Html.RenderPartial` sections.